# How can I tell when a word has derivative and flexive morphemes and when do they appear simultaneously in a word?

Tags: gramática, lingüística, morfología

I'm confused about exactly what criteria should be used to tell the difference between flexive and derivative morphemes that appear simulataneously in a single word.

Let's suppose from the words:

> personal, verdoso, legalidad and descortés

the morphemes I could spot were

- personal

  - person-al
- verdoso

  - verd-oso
- legalidad

  - legal-idad
- descortés

  - des-corté-s

But from those, which one has derivative and flexive morphemes and why?. **When** do they appear **simultaneously**? Is the way I segmented those words correct? How should they be segmented?

Comment: Welcome, Chris.  I am not a linguist, so if I got anything wrong in my edits, please undo as needed or even do a whole rollback.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks for your kindness, no problems. Since it is my first post I'm assuming that my wording might not be precise. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Flexive morphemes* are those used to make plurals (*-s*), set the gender of the word (*-o*, *-a*), or conjugate verbs (as in cant-*aré*). Strictly speaking, a word than admits a plural but is in singular form, has an empty flexive morpheme at the end, see [here](https://www.gramaticas.net/2011/01/ejemplos-de-morfema-flexivo.html):

- cosa *-Ø* (singular)
- cosa *-s* (plural)

**Derivative morphemes** change the meaning of the word, such as **-idad** in "activ **-idad**", which transforms the adjective "activo" into a noun.

Let us take a look at your examples. All derivative morphemes are highlighted in **bold**, and all flexive morphemes in *italics*:

- person **-al** (*-Ø*)

  Here, **-al** is a derivative morpheme. This is a tricky case, as "personal" might be an adjective meaning "personal" in English (in which case it has an empty flexive morpheme at the end because it admits a plural form) or it can be a noun meaning "staff" in English, in which case it has no flexive morpheme because it does not admit a plural.
- verd **-os** *-o* *-Ø*

  Here, **-os** is a derivative morpheme, which changes the meaning of "verde". The morpheme *-o* is flexive, because it sets the word as masculine. Similarly, there is an empty flexive morpheme at the end because the word is in singular form.
- legal **-idad**

  Here, **-idad** is a derivative morpheme, which changes the meaning of "legal". There are no flexive morphemes, because (as far as I know) "legalidad" has no plural form.
- **des-** cortés *-Ø*

  Here, **des-** is a derivative morpheme, and there is an empty flexive morpheme at the end because the word admits a plural form.

As you have seen in the examples, **derivative** and *flexive* morphemes often appear together in a word.

Comment: So the way to separate the word descortés would be des-cort-és. Is this the way? So in the group of words I wrote only verdoso is flexive and derivative because the morpheme **-o** is an indication of gender? as masculine (in that case), so verdos-**a** would be femenine?. But why not descortés is not also a flexive because **as it is** the word does not indicate a plural, and if it had been stated as descorteses then that would have had a derivative and flexive morpheme? with those being **des-** and **-eses**?. But morphemes ending with let's say **-oso** do have simultaneously

Comment: the characteristic of flexive and derivative?. Does it exist a list of morphemes in spanish which do have these characteristics present at the same time?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell see the updated answer. Singular words which admit a plural form technically have an *empty flexive morpheme* at the end. You are right about "verdoso".